# SharePoint 2013 Search and parser errors

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

One subsite in my SP environment, with xml-files stored. The crawl throws this error, 30k times,

> Processing this item failed because of a xml parser error

I tried to do the steps from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spblog/archive/2013/10/08/crawl-error-sharepoint-2013-processing-this-item-failed-because-of-an-unknown-error-when-trying-to-parse-its-contents.aspx) guide , but it did not work for me.

I also have a small amount of word parser error and pdf parser errors.

Here is the whole error:

> Processing this item faild because of a XML error. (Error parsing document `http://mySPSite/mySubsite/myList/theNameOfTheXMLFile.xml`. Invalid XML stream - line (6), position (19). ;; SearchID = number of the search id)

They all has the "line (6)" and the "position (19)".

What is the reason for those errors?

This is my crawllog, it recrawls even if it is incremental and full seems to have sucesfully ended.
[image]

Comment: could you please put the complete error details.

Comment: I have edited the whole error into the question.

Comment: how much space you have on Index server, c: drive and index drive? Make sure you have plenty of space on drives

Comment: Alot, 140gb on index, only 10-15 is filled, and 40-50 free on C.

Comment: is your search service account and content search account is different than the farm admin account?

Comment: It should be, but I would like to be able to confirm it, so where excatly would I could see this? Search Services in services.msc is run by my SearchService account.

Comment: I have the exact same error. Did you fix it?

Comment: Nope.. I am lost in the error...

Comment: But, since they are XML files, I think there is no need to indexing them, so I will try to exclude dem from search, and see if this will solve/remove the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this too.

Check the xml file (use "download a copy"). At that position, do you have any non-english characters there? Perhaps in the XML node name?

In that case, install the March 2015 CU for SharePoint as it fixes this particular issue. 
Look at KB2956153 for the specific fix (though their description is a bit off as it only talks about the presence of an "encoding declaration" as being the error).

Hope it helps.

An alternative solution could be to use another XML iFilter than the standard one. Could be a hard road to take though.